# Did git reset $(git merge-base master yourBranch) . Now shows 156 files changes because of all the previous commits

Tags: git, github

I was working on a pre-existing branch which had many commits already. I added a new feature and added 3 commits. Then i wanted to squash the commits but `git reset $(git merge-base master yourBranch)` did reset all the previous commits also and now git is showing 156 files changed which i didn't want. I also did the commit.

How can I get back only my changes rather than getting 156 files changes ?

```
git checkout yourBranch
git reset $(git merge-base master yourBranch)
git add -A
git commit -m "one commit on yourBranch"
git push --force origin yourBranch
```

Comment: Did you branch off of `master` and then add 3 commits? If yes, then it seems that your 3 commits did change those 156 files. Try running the command `git merge-base master yourBranch` by itself and confirm that the resulting commit ID is where your branch started.

Answer (score 0):

- To revert your local branch to what it was :

a. use `git reflog` or `git reflog yourBranch`, and spot the sha of the commit before you ran `git reset $(git merge-base master yourBranch)`

b. use `git reset <sha>`

---

You can now check your branch history, to spot the commit you want to move back to (the one "3 commits before" if I understood correctly).

I would recommend using the `--soft` option of `git reset`:

```
git reset --soft <thatcommit>
git commit
```

that way your staging area will contain exactly the same files as your last commit, and you don't have to run `git add -A` which may take in other untracked files or uncommitted local modifications

---

You will have to force push the result :

```
git push --force-with-lease origin yourBranch
```

Comment: The mistake I was doing was using master as a target branch for all source branch that is why I was getting all of the previous commits.